# How to determine number of open sockets? VM Resource Issues

Tags: linux, socket, qos

I've got a MediaTemple DV server. I've been seeing a lot of QOS alerts for "numothersock" which is defined as:

> The number of sockets other than TCP ones. Local (UNIX-domain) sockets
>   are used for communications inside the system. UDP sockets are used,
>   for example, for Domain Name Service (DNS) queries. UDP and other
>   sockets may also be used in some very specialized applications (SNMP
>   agents and others).

How can I determine what application/daemon/etc is creating these sockets? The limit is 300 and we're hitting that several times a day recently.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
netstat -nap
p shows the process id
```

Comment: Please avoid `netstat -a` it will run dns name resolution, using `-np` is fine...

Answer (score 11):

`netstat -an | grep ESTABLISHED | wc -l`

This will count all opened sockets in the system and will output just the total.
You can of course also change ESTABLISHED for whatever you need, for example a port or a communication status like CONNECTED or LISTENING.

Comment: `watch -n1 -d "netstat -an | grep ESTABLISHED | wc -l"`

Comment: instead of `grep SOMETHING| wc -l`, you could use `grep -c SOMETHING`

Answer (score 4):

To watch live MySQL opened connections through UNIX socket, run (as root):

`watch -n1 'netstat -np | grep -i mysqld'`

Answer (score 3):

## with [`ss`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/ss)

`netstat` is [deprecated](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/278474/why-is-netstat-deprecated#387406), its replacement is `ss`.

For your case, `ss -pun` might be useful that shows UDP (`-u`) sockets with process information (`-p`) and doesn't turn port numbers into service names (`-n`).

I use `ss -ptln` a lot whichs shows listening (`-l`) TCP sockets (`-t`).

It's useful with [`watch`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/watch) when you want to make sure your web application cleans up its TCP sockets:

```
watch ss -ptln
```

[Here](https://www.rootusers.com/21-ss-command-examples-in-linux/) are some more examples with `ss`.

Answer (score 1):

`netstat -a` shows'em all. Or you can study its manual page to filter out only those types of connections you're interested in.

Comment: Thanks guys! Appreciate it! In my case, it was BIND. I don't even need it running. Thanks a ton!